# contact form wrong echo

Tags: javascript, php, contact-form

form

```
<form id="contact" action="" method="post">
   <input id="name" type="text" name="name"  width="250" size="35" placeholder="Your name" required/>
     <br><br>
   <input id="email" type="text" name="email" width="250" size="35" placeholder="Your mail" required/>
   <br><br>
     <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="6" cols="40" placeholder="Your message" required></textarea>
   <br><br>
     <input type="button" value=" SEND " id="submit" />
     <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset">
     <div id="success"></div>
</form>
```

js

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
        $.post("chapters/contactphp.php", $("#contact").serialize(),  function(response) {
        $('#success').html(response);
       });
      return false;
    });
```

php

```
if((empty($_POST['name'])) || (empty($_POST['email'])) || (empty($_POST['message']))){
die("All fields must be filled !");
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = 'qadenza@gmail.com';
$subject = 'stojada contact';
$message = 'FROM: '.$name." \nEmail: ".$email."\nMessage: \n".$message;

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 
mail($to, $subject, $message); 
echo "Thank you! Your email was sent.";
}else{
echo "The email you entered, is not valid.";
}
```

All fields are filled, but echo is `All fields must be filled`.

Comment: You have of course done basic debugging like `print_r( $_POST )` to confirm that the form sends everything it should?

Comment: okay, so the question is..?

Comment: @SobinAugustine, You really don't see the question ?

Comment: Can we get answer on Juhana's question? Does form send the data? Did you check if you are actually receiving $_POST?

Comment: @sskoko, It seems the form doesn't send the data. I change `if (filter_var...` to `if (!filter_var...` and received an empty mail.

Comment: So, nothing is wrong with echo.

Comment: @sskoko, but what is then wrong ?

Comment: I don't think you should change filter_var to !filter_var. Is all this in one file or your php is in separate file?

Comment: @sskoko, php is in separate file. I also see now `if (!filter...` is not the solution, because when I entered a non-valid email - there is no echo `The email you entered, is not valid.`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38262/discussion-between-sskoko-and-sunsky)

Comment: How is the jquery code related to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**test.php**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#submit').click(function(){
                $.post("test2.php", $("#contact").serialize(),  function(response) {
                $('#success').html(response);
            });
            return false;
        });    
    });
</script>

<form id="contact" action="" method="post">
   <input id="name" type="text" name="name"  width="250" size="35" placeholder="Your name" required/>
     <br><br>
   <input id="email" type="text" name="email" width="250" size="35" placeholder="Your mail" required/>
   <br><br>
     <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="6" cols="40" placeholder="Your message" required></textarea>
   <br><br>
     <input type="button" value=" SEND " id="submit" />
     <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset">
     <div id="success"></div>
</form>
```

**test2.php**

```
<?php
if ($_POST)
{
    if((empty($_POST['name'])) || (empty($_POST['email'])) || (empty($_POST['message']))){
    die("All fields must be filled !");
    }

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $to = 'qadenza@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'stojada contact';
    $message = 'FROM: '.$name." \nEmail: ".$email."\nMessage: \n".$message;

    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 
    mail($to, $subject, $message); 
    echo "Thank you! Your email was sent.";
    }else{
    echo "The email you entered, is not valid.";
    }  
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you please shed some insight to what improvements you have made to the code instead of just posting a code solution.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [`PHP` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php), the function `filter_var` returns **false**, *or* the **filtered data**.

Comment: Thanks, Matt, this part seems solved. I change to `if (!filter...`